# Constructor not working java

Tags: java, constructor

I get an error if i try to put the parameters at the following line

```
Sum s1 = new Sum(1,5,6);
```

Why do i get this error when there is a constructor called Sum with 3 parameters

```
package test;

class Sum {
    double num1,num2,num3;
    double[] result = new double[4];
   double[] Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3; 
        result[0] = num1;
        result[1] = num2;
        result[2] = num3;
        result[4] = num1+ num2 + num3;
        return result;
    } 
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sum s1 = new Sum(1,5,6);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should know better, that "an error" is not an appropriate error description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor has return type, Constructor do not have return statements. You need to change

```
public Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3; 
        result[0] = num1;
        result[1] = num2;
        result[2] = num3;
        result[3] = num1+ num2 + num3;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ...how could i forget about that

Answer (score 4):

```
double[] Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3)
```

is not constructor

you want to have this instead:

```
public Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3)
```

here is an example of a contructor:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html

Comment: you were one second faster :D

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong (an array of length 4 has indices from 0 to 3) :

```
result[4] = num1+ num2 + num3;
```

Change to

```
result[3] = num1+ num2 + num3;
```

Beside that, a constructor shouldn't have a return value.

Change

```
double[] Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3)
```

to

```
Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3)
```

and remove the return statement.

To summarize, the constructor should look like this :

```
Sum(int num1,int num2, int num3) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.num3 = num3; 
    result[0] = num1;
    result[1] = num2;
    result[2] = num3;
    result[3] = num1+ num2 + num3;
}
```

Comment: sorry dude, I think I just edited your answer by accident

Answer (score 0):

constructor does not return any value.

A constructor does not support any return type. Not even void.

**The implicit return type by default is the class type in which it is declared.**

Answer (score 0):

You should create constructor that takes 3 int parameters, like this:

```
...
private int num1, num2, num3;

public Sum(int a, int b, int c) {
    this.num1 = a;
    this.num2 = b;
    this.num3 = c;
}
```